# What is this 'block' called in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I am looking at creating a contained block like in the notes app Bear. When you click the ‘hashtag’ icon in the Keyboard Accessory it adds a ‘contained block’ in the text view. You can then continue to write text but if you backspace it selects the whole block as if it’s a single element? It also shows it with a background colour. When you click the tag icon what is that ‘contained block’ element called? Here is the example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0j1o.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely a custom view. 
I searched their site for 3rd party libraries but can't seem to find the specific one that does this behavior. Tbf, I just skimmed. But there's a possibility it could be their own code.

3rd-party libraries used: https://bear.app/faq/Extra/Libraries%20used%20in%20Bear/